# Creation of Siyee and Elai

Tags: trudi-canavan, age-of-five

In the Age of Five we are introduced to human groups that have been mutated by the magic of Huan into flying people (Siyee) and Sea people (Elai).

When were the Siyee and Elai created out of the human root-stock? Was this during the Age of Five or the Age of Many?